# JPA StackOverflowError when loading data in relationship tables

Tags: jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, stack-overflow, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to implement loading in three tables ([the beginning of the problem with mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922933/how-to-bind-the-entity-through-the-additional-table-with-a-composite-key))

`Products`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductProperty> productPropertyCollection;

    ...
}
```

`Properties`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties")
public class Property implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductProperty> productPropertyCollection;

    ...
}
```

`Product_Property`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_property")
public class ProductProperty implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ProductPropertyPK productPropertyPK;

    @MapsId(value = "propertyId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne()    
    private Property property;

    @MapsId(value = "productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne()
    private Product product;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ProductPropertyPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int productId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "property_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int propertyId;
    ...
}
```

It works fine for 1, 10, 100 products, but somewhere there is an error, because for 1000 and more products throws error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:443)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:434)
    at java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4141)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:938)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4178)
...
```

when i'm creating ProductProperty, i'm setting `product` and `property` in `ProductProperty`, and adding to collection for bidirection in `Product` and `Property`.

where i could make a mistake?

Comment: Not related, but you might remove the NotNull and Column annotations in the embedded id.  Since the relationship mapping is marked as MapsId, the field is defined through the relationship and these annotations only confuse things.  That, and it can be null, since you never directly set it anymore - JPA does later on.

Comment: @Chris as you say, i remove all annotations, but this does not solve the problem. I try set -Xss10m (for test infinite loop), and all work fine. so no the problem in the algorithm of filling entities. remains only `annotations` or `size of stack`

Comment: Looks like your object model complexity or depth is just difficult to traverse within your JVM's stack limits.  As it is, every entity seems reachable from every other entity, which causes problems when traversed recursivelyTry increasing the -Xss setting.  You might also reduce the interconnectivity, such as removing one of the OneToMany mappings and query for it directly instead of storing it in the Product or Property mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your object model complexity or depth is just difficult to traverse within your JVM's stack limits.  As it is, every entity seems reachable from every other entity, which causes problems when traversed recursively. Try increasing the -Xss setting.  You might also reduce the interconnectivity, such as removing one of the OneToMany mappings and query for it directly instead of storing it in the Product or Property mapping.  You might also file an enhancement with EclipseLink to traverse the object graph using a stack instead of recursively.

Comment: I looked at the problem from the other side, and decided that I really need other relations. In fact, I don't need to store the `property` OneToMany relation (if it needed i can use query), and i don't `product` OneToMany ralation to `productProperty`, but i need `product` OneToMany relation to `property` through `productProperty`. Next step - realize it and check StackOverflowError